# unable to see the custom attribute finder in wso2 IS as KM 5.10.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Hi I am using wso2 IS as KM with APIM 3.1.0 .

I want to create custom attribute finder in wso2 ID server. I followed this link 
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/develop/writing-a-custom-policy-info-point/

But at the end I am not able to see the custom attribute finder in wso2 ID server under PDP extension view.

I have include the following data source in entitlement.properties

```
DataSourceName=jdbc/testuserstore
```

Init method in KmarketJDBCAttributeFinder looks like this:

```
@Override
    public void init(Properties properties)  throws Exception{

        String dataSourceName = (String) properties.get("DataSourceName");

        if(dataSourceName == null || dataSourceName.trim().length() == 0){
            throw new Exception("Data source name can not be null. Please configure it in the entitlement.properties file.");
        }

        dataSource = (DataSource) InitialContext.doLookup(dataSourceName);
        ................
        ...............
```

and I have include below configs in deployment.toml file

```
[server]
hostname = "10.57.8.4"
node_ip = "10.57.8.4"
base_path = "https://$ref{server.hostname}:${carbon.management.port}"
serverDetails = "WSO2 IS as KM 5.10.0"
mode = "single"
userAgent = "WSO2 IS as KM 5.10.0"

[super_admin]
username = "admin"
password = "admin"
create_admin_account = true

[user_store]
type = "database_unique_id"

[database.apim_db]
type = "postgre"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://10.57.8.45:5432/wso2apimdb"
username = "wso2apim"
password = "password"
driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1"

[database.shared_db]
type = "postgre"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://10.57.8.45:5432/wso2shareddb"
username = "wso2shared"
password = "password"
driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1"


[[apim.gateway.environment]]
name = "Production and Sandbox"
type = "hybrid"
description = "This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic."
service_url = "https://10.57.8.46:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
username= "${admin.username}"
password= "${admin.password}"

[keystore.primary]
file_name = "idserver.jks"
password = "password"
alias = "idserver"
key_password = "password"

[admin_service.wsdl]
enable= true

[[datasource]]
id = "testuserstore"
#type = "postgre"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://10.57.8.45:5432/testuserstore"
username = "testuser"
password = "password"
#driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
#validationQuery = "SELECT 1"


[[xacml.pip.attribute_designator]]
class = "org.xacmlinfo.xacml.pip.jdbc.KMarketJDBCAttributeFinder"
[xacml.pip.attribute_designator.properties]
DataSourceName = "jdbc/testuserstore"


[[event_listener]]
id = "mutual_tls_authenticator"
type = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.handler.AbstractIdentityHandler"
name = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handler.clientauth.mutualtls.MutualTLSClientAuthenticator"
order = "158"
enable = false

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls=["tcp://10.57.8.46:9611"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls=["ssl://10.57.8.46:9711"]
type = "loadbalance"
```

testuserstore is the database created in postgresql DB. I have created tables in the database as mentioned in the link. Also included postgres jdbc driver and org.xacmlinfo.xacml.pip.jdbc-1.0.0.jar into the /repository/components/lib. I am using jdk 8 for building the jar file.

Please let me know where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following configuration to register a custom attribute finder.

```
[identity.entitlement.policy_point.pip]
attribute_designators = [
  "org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.pip.DefaultAttributeFinder",
  "org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authz.xacml.pip.AuthenticationContextAttributePIP",
  "org.xacmlinfo.xacml.pip.jdbc.KMarketJDBCAttributeFinder"
]
```

A [public jira](https://github.com/wso2/docs-is/issues/1782) is raised against the product documentation to update the documentation accordingly.

The required **Datasource** should be defined as a property of the custom attribute finder. Due to an identified limitation of the product, the extension package name should be in the format of,
`org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.{{extension.name}}`. This is tracked in [https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/8450.](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/8450)

As a workaround to get the sample work, you can follow in one of the following ways. Option 2 is not recommended since the config template files are not supposed to be modified.

**Option 1:**

1. Change the package of the sample as  `org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.KMarketJDBCAttributeFinder`.
2. Do the configurations in the deployment.toml as follows.

> ```
> [identity.entitlement.policy_point.pip]
> attribute_designators = [
>   "org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.pip.DefaultAttributeFinder",
>   "org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authz.xacml.pip.AuthenticationContextAttributePIP",
>   "org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.KMarketJDBCAttributeFinder"
> ]
> [[identity.entitlement.extension]]
> name="KMarketJDBCAttributeFinder"
> [identity.entitlement.extension.properties]
> DataSourceName = "jdbc/KMARKETUSERDB"
> ```

**Option 2:**
By this way, you can have any package name as the custom attribute finder.

1. Edit the **entitlement.properties.j2** file in */repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/identity* directory.
2. Search for **identity.entitlement.extension** and change the templated configs as follows.

> ```
> {% if identity.entitlement.extension is defined %}
> {% for extension in identity.entitlement.extension %}
> {% for key,value in extension.properties.items() %}
> {{extension.name}}.{{loop.index}}={{key}},{{value}}
> {% endfor %}
> {% endfor %}
> {% endif %}
> ```

3. Do the configurations in the deployment.toml as follows.

> ```
> [identity.entitlement.policy_point.pip]
> attribute_designators = [
>   "org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.pip.DefaultAttributeFinder",
>   "org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authz.xacml.pip.AuthenticationContextAttributePIP",
>   "org.xacmlinfo.xacml.pip.jdbc.KMarketJDBCAttributeFinder"
> ]
> [[identity.entitlement.extension]]
> name="org.xacmlinfo.xacml.pip.jdbc.KMarketJDBCAttributeFinder"
> [identity.entitlement.extension.properties]
> DataSourceName = "jdbc/KMARKETUSERDB"
> ```

Thanks

Comment: Is it necessary to specify a datasource if there is none siphoned yet (for testing)?

And is there a naming convention for the extension jar file in <wso is folder>/repository/components/lib?